# Has anyone cycled London to Fishguard?

Tags: london

I'm planning a company charity ride to Dublin and was wondering how hard the route was and how many days to expect to take?

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles! This is not a forum; this is a questions and answer site, and I'm afraid your post isn't really a question, because [real questions have answers, not items or ideas or opinions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/). Please read [the FAQ](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It seems likely, since that is exactly [NCN 4](http://www.sustrans.org.uk/what-we-do/national-cycle-network/route-numbering-system/route-4) - however, I haven't found any references to people riding the length of route 4, and the CTC route database isn't giving me anything either.

For reference, I plugged Charing Cross to Fishguard into [cyclestreets](http://www.cyclestreets.net/journey/1840481/) and it reckons a shade under 300 miles (for the *balanced* route). Whether that means three consecutive 100-mile days, or five 60-mile days will depend on you.

I'd take the cyclestreets routes with a grain of salt, or at least study them carefully (and compare with the sustrans route description and mapping linked above).

Oh, and I see about 2km of total ascent on that route, with what look like some steepish sections once you're into Wales.